# PHP imap, send to message id?

Tags: php, email

I'm building a php application that can read, reply and send emails.  I use php imap to retrieve the emails.  Each email has a `message-id` that looks like `5981e1f444a81f1fc60549beb91ce060bc795d20@domain.co.uk`.  I attempted to reply to this specific message with my php application but not working.    I'm using `test@domain.co.uk` as mail server, i retrieve emails to my php application with php imap.  Each email has a message-id, how do i reply to a specific message?  How do i solve?; the below example doesn't work.

```
/* try to connect */
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to email: ' . imap_last_error());

    /* grab emails */
    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

    /* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
    if($emails) {

        /* begin output var */
        $output = '';

        /* put the newest emails on top */
        rsort($emails);

        /* for every email... */
        foreach($emails as $email_number) {

            /* get information specific to this email */
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
            $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);


                $headers = "From: test@plantsandtreesonline.co.uk \r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$overview[0]->message_id."\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $subject = "testing";
        $message = "test message2";
        wp_mail( $overview[0]->message_id, $subject, $message, $headers );

        }

        echo $output;
    } 

    /* close the connection */
    imap_close($inbox);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want "In-Reply-To:" instead of "Reply-To:" for the header with the message id. "Reply-To" would be an email address - who the reply should be sent to.